# Keep the LocatedSpan of an "outer" parser with nom in Rust

Tags: rust, lexer, nom

I am trying to write a parser using the `nom` crate (and the `nom_locate`) that can parse strings such as `u{12a}`, i.e.:

```
u\{([0-9a-fA-F]{1,6})\}
```

I wrote the following parser combinator:

```rust
use nom::bytes::complete::{take_while_m_n};
use nom::character::complete::{char};
use nom::combinator::{map_opt, map_res};

use nom::sequence::{delimited, preceded};


pub type LocatedSpan<'a> = nom_locate::LocatedSpan<&'a str>;
pub type IResult<'a, T> = nom::IResult<LocatedSpan<'a>, T>;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct LexerError<'a>(LocatedSpan<'a>, String);

fn expect<'a, F, E, T>(
    mut parser: F,
    err_msg: E,
) -> impl FnMut(LocatedSpan<'a>) -> IResult<Option<T>>
where
    F: FnMut(LocatedSpan<'a>) -> IResult<T>,
    E: ToString,
{
    use nom::error::Error as NomError;
    move |input| match parser(input) {
        Ok((remaining, output)) => Ok((remaining, Some(output))),
        Err(nom::Err::Error(NomError { input, code: _ }))
        | Err(nom::Err::Failure(NomError { input, code: _ })) => {
            let err = LexerError(input, err_msg.to_string());
            // TODO Report error.
            println!("error: {:?}", err);
            Ok((input, None))
        }
        Err(err) => Err(err),
    }
}

fn lit_str_unicode_char(input: LocatedSpan) -> IResult<char> {
    let parse_hex = take_while_m_n(1, 6, |c: char| c.is_ascii_hexdigit());
    // FIXME Figure out a way to keep correct span here.
    let parse_delim_hex = preceded(
        char('u'),
        delimited(
            char('{'),
            expect(parse_hex, "expected 1-6 hex digits"),
            expect(char('}'), "expected closing brace"),
        ),
    );
    let parse_u32 = map_res(parse_delim_hex, move |hex| match hex {
        None => Err("cannot parse number"),
        Some(hex) => match u32::from_str_radix(hex.fragment(), 16) {
            Ok(val) => Ok(val),
            Err(_) => Err("invalid number"),
        },
    });
    map_opt(parse_u32, std::char::from_u32)(input)
}

fn main() {
    let raw = "u{61}";
    let span = LocatedSpan::new(raw);
    let result = lit_str_unicode_char(span);
    println!("{:#?}", result);
}
```

This works correctly, I am able to get the Unicode character out of the string. However, this approach does not keep the proper spans, i.e.:

```
u{123}
\..../  <--- the span I want
     \/ <--- the span I get
```

I figured I could wrap the `parse_delim_hex` in a `recognize`, which would keep the span correctly, but then I couldn't use the following parsers to "understand" the digits.

How should I get around this issue?

Comment: Sure, let me prepare that now!

Comment: Are you sure you are not reading the wrong span? The span in `Ok(span, char)` is the span that is left over **after** you found the token.

Comment: @Finomnis I updated the example. I apologize, it's a bit long. I tried removing the `expect`, but then the example wouldn't compile, so I decided to keep it there. The area of interest is actually just the `lit_str_unicode_char` function.

Comment: Why do you use `nom_locate`? From what I can see, you don't actually accept inputs like `"    u{61}"`, which is the whole point of `nom_locate`. Do you want to *parse* the value or do you want to *locate* it?

Comment: I use nom locate for the large parser. I am writing a parser for a DSL. This is meant to be used in other parsers.

Comment: Yes, I get that, but what is it supposed to do? Does it expect that the unicode tag is at the first position, or is it supposed to search it first? Otherwise, it's easy to answer where the unicode is, it's at position 0.
Further I don't understand what you mean with *"does not keep the proper spans"*; it does exactly what it's supposed to do, it gives you the span **after** the parsed content, just as intended by `nom`.

Comment: Yes sir, you are absolutely right. I don't know how but I looked at it a million times and never saw the actual issue. What I need to return from there is not a `char`, but a `Token` (or something that contains a LocatedSpan itself). Then I can effectively return a token containing the `input` as span and the parsed `char`. I believe the best way to proceed would be deleting the question now, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the purpose of the first parameter of [`IResult`](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/type.IResult.html).

Quote from the documentation:

> The Ok side is a pair containing the remainder of the input (the part of the data that was not parsed) and the produced value.

The `span` you are looking at is **not** the data that was found, but instead the data that was left over afterwards.

I think what you were trying to achieve is something along those lines:

```
use nom::bytes::complete::take_while_m_n;
use nom::character::complete::char;
use nom::combinator::{map_opt, map_res};
use nom::{InputTake, Offset};

use nom::sequence::{delimited, preceded};

pub type LocatedSpan<'a> = nom_locate::LocatedSpan<&'a str>;
pub type IResult<'a, T> = nom::IResult<LocatedSpan<'a>, T>;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct LexerError<'a>(LocatedSpan<'a>, String);

fn expect<'a, F, E, T>(
    mut parser: F,
    err_msg: E,
) -> impl FnMut(LocatedSpan<'a>) -> IResult<Option<T>>
where
    F: FnMut(LocatedSpan<'a>) -> IResult<T>,
    E: ToString,
{
    use nom::error::Error as NomError;
    move |input| match parser(input) {
        Ok((remaining, output)) => Ok((remaining, Some(output))),
        Err(nom::Err::Error(NomError { input, code: _ }))
        | Err(nom::Err::Failure(NomError { input, code: _ })) => {
            let err = LexerError(input, err_msg.to_string());
            // TODO Report error.
            println!("error: {:?}", err);
            Ok((input, None))
        }
        Err(err) => Err(err),
    }
}

fn lit_str_unicode_char(input: LocatedSpan) -> IResult<(char, LocatedSpan)> {
    let parse_hex = take_while_m_n(1, 6, |c: char| c.is_ascii_hexdigit());
    // FIXME Figure out a way to keep correct span here.
    let parse_delim_hex = preceded(
        char('u'),
        delimited(
            char('{'),
            expect(parse_hex, "expected 1-6 hex digits"),
            expect(char('}'), "expected closing brace"),
        ),
    );
    let parse_u32 = map_res(parse_delim_hex, |hex| match hex {
        None => Err("cannot parse number"),
        Some(hex) => match u32::from_str_radix(hex.fragment(), 16) {
            Ok(val) => Ok(val),
            Err(_) => Err("invalid number"),
        },
    });

    // Do the actual parsing
    let (s, ch) = map_opt(parse_u32, std::char::from_u32)(input)?;
    let span_offset = input.offset(&s);
    let span = input.take(span_offset);
    Ok((s, (ch, span)))
}

fn main() {
    let span = LocatedSpan::new("u{62} bbbb");
    let (rest, (ch, span)) = lit_str_unicode_char(span).unwrap();
    println!("Leftover: {:?}", rest);
    println!("Character: {:?}", ch);
    println!("Parsed Span: {:?}", span);
}
```

```
Leftover: LocatedSpan { offset: 5, line: 1, fragment: " bbbb", extra: () }
Character: 'b'
Parsed Span: LocatedSpan { offset: 0, line: 1, fragment: "u{62}", extra: () }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I wanted to achieve.